# How to click on popup on firefox using Geb

Tags: firefox, selenium-webdriver, geb

I am writing tests using Geb. The browser I am using is Firefox. I want to click on a drop-down list that appears once the menu button is clicked. I can click on the menu button which gives me the drop-down list but I can't select the Item I want, Firefox just hangs. Chrome works just fine.

Here is my code :

```
container.menuButton.click() // this works fine. A list of appears.
container.menuOption("Coke").click() // the selection doesn't happen here it just hangs
```

How can I get Firefoxto work?

Comment: Can you write `menuOption()` function implementation? I think problem in here.

Comment: menuOption { String option ->                                       
def menuClasses = [
                "Coke":"COKE",
                "Fanta":"FANTA",
                "Sprite":"SPRITE"
                ]

           find(".menu-container .item.${menuClasses[option]}")
        }

Comment: Is this just a simple HTML select that you are using as your "drop-down" list?